# Drawing vertical lines in multiple graphs plot

Tags: r, plot

While using the **mirt** package, I came across using plot function which allows us to draw multiple characteristic curves in the same plot as attache din the image file.

The code I am using to get this plot is as below

```
library(mirt)
data(LSAT6)
mod=mirt(LSAT6, 1, "Rasch")
plot(mod, type = 'trace', auto.key = F, main="Item Information Curves")
```

I want to draw a vertical line in all sub-graphs shown in the image, at point zero.

Anyone knows hoe to do it?

Thank you in advance.

P.S.   `abline(v=0, col=3, lwd=1)` is not working for this purpose.

[image: Item information curve]

How I need my graph to be look like this ( did this using paint) :

[image: Desired Item Information Curve with Vertical line]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plot uses the [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) graphics system. The lines can be added with a custom panel function (see `?xyplot`):

```
plot(mod, type = 'trace', auto.key = F, , main="Item Information Curves",
 panel=function(...) {
   panel.xyplot(...)
   if (which.packet() %in% c(2, 3, 5, 6)) {
     panel.abline(v=0, col="red", lwd=3)
   }
   if (which.packet() %in% 4) {
     panel.abline(v=0, col="black", lwd=3)
   }
 })
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what mirt is doing but that looks like a lattice plot. To add other plots you use the panel argument. For example:

```
library(reshape2)
d=melt(iris)
xyplot(value~variable|Species,d,panel=function(x,y,...) {
    panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
    panel.abline(v = 1)
})
```

Maybe the plot() function you are using accepts a panel argument?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! Will surely keep this in mind next time! :)